# Mac OSX unable to SSH connection reset by peer

Tags: macos, networking, ssh

I have an SSH server running at home and I am trying to connect to it from school. But when I try to connect I get:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

However, when I ssh from a different client, it works fine. Same SSH version, same OS. When I do:

```
$ssh me@xx.xxx.xxx.xx -vv
```

I get:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 72.135.103.38 [72.135.103.38] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/mdow7299/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/mdow7299/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mdow7299/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mdow7299/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

So other clients are able to SSH into the server, but I cannot. It's definitely a client side issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/857206/54530

Comment: Other clients where?  Also at school?