# SSH Connection reset by peer

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

When I tried to connect with ssh from my Ubuntu 20 , I got that error

```
root@home:/home/home/Desktop# ssh 192.168.1.1 -v
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/857206/54530

Comment: after you check if the sshd is running correctly on the server and that your client IP is not denied on the server, try again and if it fails check the server ssh log and provide output from your ssh attempt with `-vvv` which gives more verbose output. BTW, what is 192.168.1.1? that is a common router IP - if it is and the router was provided by your ISP - doubt you will be able to ssh.